# Weird Interaction between level 4 header and code chunk

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am using R Studio for one of my classes (reproducible on R Studio Cloud) and I've been running into a bug where if a level 4 header is above an R code chunk with `echo=T`, the header will appear below the first code chunk. This only happens when output is PDF. Here's a picture to show what I mean:

[image: Knitted PDF Output]

And here's an example of what anything above a level 4 header looks like (pictured is a level 3 header):

[image: Knitted PDF Output]

Both examples are built from the Magma Demo rmd file from R Studio Cloud. Also, since StackOverflow's editor and RStudio's Rmd files are both in Markdown, I can't post the code without breaking the editor, so here's a picture of the code:

[image: Code]

Is this intended? Or am I doing something wrong? Many thanks in advance.

P.S. This question was also cross-posted at https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1896.